# Proof writing involving power sets: $A \subseteq P(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove: $A \subseteq P(A)$

Suppose $x\in A$.

[Proof here]

Therefore, not $P(A)$

How can one prove or disprove this theorem?

I know the theorem is false but I don't see how to disprove it. Any help? How do you disprove a theorem?

Comment: $P(A)$ is the set of subsets of $A$, so its elements are subsets of $A$ and $A$ is an element of $P(A)$, but the subsets of $P(A)$ are sets of subsets of $A$, so $A$ is not a subset of $P(A)$, but $\{A\}$ is a subset of $P(A)$.

Comment: @Emilio: It is not correct to automatically state that $A$ is not a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$. It *could* be a subset. For example the empty set is a subset of its power set.

Comment: A set that is a subset of its own power set is called a _transitive_ set. There are many transitive sets, but not all sets are transitive.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Good point! But the void set is the only set with such property... or not?

Comment: @EmilioNovati: There are proper-class many sets with this property -- such as each of the Von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: thank you! I've learned something !

Comment: @EmilioNovati Consider also $V_n=P(P(\dotsb(P(\emptyset))\dotsb))$, with $n\ $ $P$s. (This satisfies $V_0\subset V_1\subset V_2\subset\dotsb$. The notation doesn't end here; $V_\omega$ is defined to be $V_0\cup V_1\cup V_2\cup\dotsb$. $V_{\omega+1}$ is defined to be $P(V_\omega)$. It continues through all of the ordinals.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disproving a statement means coming up with a counterexample. (You do not disprove a theorem, since a theorem is a statement which has been proved.)

In this case, you need to find a set $A$ such that $A\nsubseteq\mathcal P(A)$. This means that you want to find a set $A$ and an element of $A$ which is not a subset of $A$.

I'll leave it to you to find such example.

Comment: Could you provide an example that disproves a statement (any statement)? how do you write a counterexample for a statement? & thanks

Comment: Steve, for example "Statement: if $A$ is a set, then $\varnothing\in A$" *"Counterexample: This is not true for $A=\varnothing$, since $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$."*